# encode json array in lua

Tags: arrays, json, lua, encode

I need to encode a json object with an array from a lua table.

```
function encode_flow_record(type,a, b, c)
    local i = 1
    while (parent~= nil) do
         local array[i] = {f1=a,f2=b,f3=c}
         parent, a,b,c = next(a,b,c)
         i = i + 1
    end

    local datastring = cjson.encode({flowrecord=type, ancestors=array})
```

When I print datastring, it shows "ancestors":{}

What am I missing?

Comment: Please ignore the uninitialized parent in the first iteration of the loop (code snippet is a shortened version). The question is about how to encode the array[]

Comment: `local array[i] = ...` is not valid Lua code.

Comment: You have to initialize your table outside the `while` statement.
`local array = {}`